# How can I stop a ray from passing through a GameObject (using XR Ray Interactor)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm building a simple scene with a road and houses. The player is able to teleport on the roads (which are planes). [image]

However, when the ray hits a house it just goes through and allows the player to teleport inside it as far as the plane extends: [image]

How can I detect whenever the ray hits a house so I can prevent the player from teleporting? Visually blocking the ray from passing through the house would be even better.

My initial idea was to use layers and I added the houses to a "House" layer and the roads to a "Road" layer. Now the next step would be to check whether the GameObject hit by the ray is in the Road or House layer but I can't find a way to detect the object.

When I add a Mesh Collider to a house the ray turns red when hitting it but as long as the ray ends on a road I can still teleport through the house.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to write your own script to let the ray detect the layer. Just create two layers, and inside the XR ray interactor, set the Raycast Mask to include the 'wall' layer. This ensures that the ray is blocked by the collider of the wall game object. The wall in my scene will block the teleport ray from the player as long as the Raycast Mask includes the 'wall' layer.